# Restore colors of Terminal to normal on ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, colors

I tried to increase size of pointer by following the instructions I found on (61) using:

```
sudo update-alternatives --config x-cursor-theme
```

My terminal background turned white and I am not sure what to do to get it back to black.

Can someone assist me please?

Comment: Have you tried editing terminal preferences?

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
gconftool --recursive-unset /apps/gnome-terminal
```

or: 
In terminal click on the 'Edit' menu then 'Profile Preferences'. It will pop up the 'Editing Profile' Window. To reset the color make sure that you have selected the check box named 'Use colors from system theme' in the 'Colors' tab.

Comment: Thank you for your help. The first command made no difference. I did try the edit menu but to get the terminal looking correct I had to set the built in theme to white on black and un check colors from the theme. If I check this this block everything goes back to a white background.